# How to change Highchart tooltip font family

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I want to change the font of highchart. How can I change these? changed x axis and y axis labels, but i can't change the tooltip font

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minWidth: 700
        },
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Bonbon'
       
        }
    },

    data: {
        csvURL: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/analytics.csv',
        beforeParse: function (csv) {
            return csv.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n');
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Daily sessions at www.highcharts.com'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
        tickWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: -3
        }
    },

    yAxis: [{ // left y axis
        title: {
            text: null
        },
         tooltip: {
        
        backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        useHTML: false,
        style: {
            padding: 0
        }
    },
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }, { // right y axis
        linkedTo: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }],

    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function (e) {
                        hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                            pageOrigin: {
                                x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                            },
                            headingText: this.series.name,
                            maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                                this.y + ' sessions',
                            width: 200
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'All sessions',
        lineWidth: 4,
        marker: {
            radius: 4
        }
    }, {
        name: 'New users'
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
font-family:Bonbon!important;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bonbon&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/css/highslide.css" />


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `style{}` in your `tooltip` it will be work's or [refer this documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.style.color)

```
style: {
   fontFamily:'Bonbon'
}
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minWidth: 700
        },
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Bonbon'
       
        }
    },

    data: {
        csvURL: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/analytics.csv',
        beforeParse: function (csv) {
            return csv.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n');
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Daily sessions at www.highcharts.com'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
        tickWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: -3
        }
    },

    yAxis: [{ // left y axis
        title: {
            text: null
        },
         tooltip: {
        
        backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        useHTML: false,
        style: {
            padding: 0
        }
    },
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }, { // right y axis
        linkedTo: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }],

    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true,
        style: {
            //fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontFamily:'Bonbon'
        }
    },
    

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function (e) {
                        hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                            pageOrigin: {
                                x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                            },
                            headingText: this.series.name,
                            maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                                this.y + ' sessions',
                            width: 200
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'All sessions',
        lineWidth: 4,
        marker: {
            radius: 4
        }
    }, {
        name: 'New users'
    }]
});
```

```css
/*-- or you try with css --*/

/*.highcharts-tooltip > text > tspan {
  font-family: Bonbon !important;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bonbon&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/css/highslide.css" />


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the tooltip, you should use this :

```
.highcharts-tooltip > text > tspan {
font-family: Bonbon !important;

}
```

[Link to JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cLoyzbg/)

Answer (score 0):

if tooltip useHTML is true then

```
.highcharts-tooltip > span{
font-family: Bonbon !important;
}
```